# How to load custom UIView from xib file into a UIView in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created a xib file.
[image]

Below is the code:

```
#import "LoginView.h"
@implementation LoginView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self setup];
}
return self;
}

-(void) setup{
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginView" owner:self options:nil];

self.bounds = self.loginView.bounds;

[self addSubview:self.loginView];
}
```

Now I created a view controller and add a UIView to it. In viewWillAppear, I am trying to load the xib file into a defined UIView in my view controller.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
self.containerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.containerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.containerView.frame.origin.x,self.containerView.frame.origin.y, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height)];
[self.containerView addSubview:loginView];
}
```

But, the xib file is going outside the defined UIView which I named containerView. I have linked the containerView to UIView in ViewController.

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
```

Can anyone help me why I am getting this output? I need to get the custom uiview inside the containerView in ViewController. Like the textfields and buttons should be inside the black border.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding your view on container view then x and y should be 0,0

You need to replace this :

```
LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.containerView.frame.origin.x,self.containerView.frame.origin.y, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height)];
```

by this:

```
LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height)];
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Now, the custom view is inside the defined container view. But it does not fit the view. How to perfectly, fit the custom view inside a container view>

Comment: could you give a screenshot , how does it show now .

Comment: the container view is expanding , isn't the width , height of container view and login view same?
have u used auto layout ?

Comment: yes, but the custom view is not fitting exactly inside the container view.